# How to draw a smooth curve in pgfplots? And how to remove y-axis ticks?

Tags: latex, pgf

I'm preparing a presentation using Latex beamer. I've decided to include a plot.

[image]

The middle curve is supposed to be a normal distribution; but it has sharp corners. Why is that?

Also, can I remove the tick marks on the y-axis?

Here is my code:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-1:1]
\addplot+[no markers] {4*exp(-4*(x+1))};
\addplot+[no markers] {1/sqrt(2*pi*0.02)*exp(-(x^2)/(2*0.02))};
\addplot+[no markers] {4*exp(4*(x-1))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{frame}
```

Thanks

Comment: In the future, please don't ask multiple questions in the same post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To get smooth curves, increase the number of sample points, e.g. `samples=100`
- To remove the y axis lables: `yticklabels=\empty`

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-1:1,samples=100,yticklabels=\empty]
\addplot+[no markers] {4*exp(-4*(x+1))};
\addplot+[no markers] {1/sqrt(2*pi*0.02)*exp(-(x^2)/(2*0.02))};
\addplot+[no markers] {4*exp(4*(x-1))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]